# Plotting a Python function in Sage Math

Tags: python, plot, sage

I have been trying to plot the Arithmetic-Geometric Mean of `1` and some non-negative number `x` using Sage Math, but am struggling to get the `plot` function to accept a Python function as input:

```
plot(agm(1,x), (x,0,5))
```

Yields the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot evaluate symbolic expression to a numeric value.
```

Where `agm(x,y)` is defined as follows:

```
def agm(x,y):
    x,y = RDF(x),RDF(y)
    a = (x+y)/2
    g = sqrt(x*y)
    diff = a-g
    while diff > (1/10**11):
        newa = (a + g)/2
        newg = sqrt(a*g)
        a,g = newa,newg
        diff = a - g
    return a
```

I have tried substituting `x` for `x.n()` when plotting, but that doesn't change anything.

How can I plot this Python function?

Comment: @DavidG The example above *is* minimal, complete and verifiable. What's wrong with it?

Comment: @DavidG I notice that you have never answered any questions regarding Sage Math in particular, so I thought I'd explain a bit. Sage is a complete suite of Math programs, so you don't need to include individual packages. You can run the code above here: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/

Comment: Yeah you're right. Using the link provided and running the code, the error seems to be with the line `x,y = RDF(x),RDF(y)` but that's all I know. Might be good to include that whole error message in this question?

Comment: Is [`plot(lambda x: agm(1, x), (0, 5))`](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxFj00OgjAQRvck3GGWnTIEauLGRFfGA3iDMZRKAqiIob29LeVnumj63nS-TKVrYNMJS-DwlCbgy5KDM9yvN2GRwuUwCvZY2MxhcYjAePD9DKOwcu2pmrr2lHMT39OzaXWkFxCqUKWUSq1RoXo9zYMZMjDb6MVsCSwN7oYpiPCTQtMu1njIYaGDHn9DD5wm4bzb1yha7h4Vgz3Nqyvya4Io6Yj4B0RTP0U=&lang=sage) what you want?

Comment: In such situations lambdas are great, nice comment.

Comment: Even simpler: [`plot(RR(1).agm,(0,5))`](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwryMkv0QgK0jDU1EtMz9XRMNAx1dQEAEbyBag=&lang=sage)

Answer (score 0):

If I run this code

[image: sagemath code]

without the `RDF` it gives me a plot. With the `RDF` it fails.

In Sage `RDF` is a real double field. In Python floats are already double, if that's what you're getting at.